# Ruby syntax '{:age.gt => 60}', how does it work?

Tags: ruby, mongoid

I am wondering this syntax `{:age.gt => 60}`, which I find this syntax from `mongoid`. How does it work? I'm checking the source code of mongoid, it didn't extend the `Symbol` class much, and there is a `matchers` directory which contains gt.rb, lt.rb, .... These files are used for conditioning logic: greater than, less than .... I can't understand how it relates to `Symbol` class.

In plain irb session, it displays an error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `gt' for :age:Symbol
```

Anyone could explain me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done by mongoid itself as part of `Mongoid::Criterion::Complex` in [this symbol inflections file](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/2.4.0-stable/lib/mongoid/extensions/symbol/inflections.rb). Oddly this file is no longer there in the master branch, but I'm using 2.4.7 in my project and it exists there (it probably just moved but I can't find it in master).

Pretty interesting bit of magic. Magic I wouldn't consider all that necessary, `:field => { :$gt => 5 }` looks just fine to me, but anyway :)

Comment: I clone it from github and do a search on my laptop with the master branch. That's why i couldn't see it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

See @rfunduk's answer for the current released version of 2.4.10.

In the master branch, it has changed. You'll now find this in the `origin` library which `mongoid` requires:

https://github.com/mongoid/origin/blob/master/lib/origin/extensions/symbol.rb, specifically this method:

```
module Origin
  module Extensions
    module Symbol
      # ...
      module ClassMethods
        # Adds a method on symbol as a convenience for the MongoDB operator.
        #
        # @example Add the $in method.
        #   Symbol.add_key(:in, "$in")
        #
        # @param [ Symbol ] name The name of the method.
        # @param [ Symbol ] strategy The name of the merge strategy.
        # @param [ String ] operator The MongoDB operator.
        # @param [ String ] additional The additional MongoDB operator.
        #
        # @since 1.0.0
        def add_key(name, strategy, operator, additional = nil, &block)
          define_method(name) do
            method = "__#{strategy}__".to_sym
            Key.new(self, method, operator, additional, &block)
          end
        end

        # ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It adds methods for `gt`, `gte`, etc. based on the matchers listed in the main `mongoid` library (see the `strategies.rb` file and `matchers/` folder).

Comment: Ah so this is why I can't find it in the master branch. Looks like a lot of work going on over there right now!

Comment: Yeah.. updated to show that my answer only applies to the master branch right now.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the relevant code is [here](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/2.4.0-stable/lib/mongoid/extensions/symbol/inflections.rb) (`Mongoid::Extensions::Symbol::Inflections`). It's sometimes easiest to dig into these things at runtime using `Tracer`:

```
require 'tracer'
require 'mongoid'

Tracer.on {
  :test.gt
}
```

outputs

```
#0:(irb):9:Object:-: -
#0:(eval):1:Mongoid::Extensions::Symbol::Inflections:>: -
#0:(eval):2:Mongoid::Extensions::Symbol::Inflections:-: -
#0:/home/abe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@deleteme/gems/mongoid-2.4.10/lib/mongoid/criterion/complex.rb:21:Mongoid::Criterion::Complex:>:       def initialize(opts = {})
#0:/home/abe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@deleteme/gems/mongoid-2.4.10/lib/mongoid/criterion/complex.rb:22:Mongoid::Criterion::Complex:-:         @key, @operator = opts[:key], opts[:operator]
#0:/home/abe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@deleteme/gems/mongoid-2.4.10/lib/mongoid/criterion/complex.rb:23:Mongoid::Criterion::Complex:<:       end
#0:(eval):3:Mongoid::Extensions::Symbol::Inflections:<: -
```

Comment: Ah, thanks alot. A nice way to trace the code. I never know it before.

Comment: No problem. Too bad rfunduk beat me by a few minutes! `(╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻`

Answer (score 0):

#### Keep looking...

...ways to define that scoping DSL are

- monkey patch either `Symbol` or `Object` directly with the method
- add `method_missing` and parse the name for meaning

Comment: I can't find any code inside method_missing, symbol, object to do that job.